# dynatree - Updating node Display Order on node drag n drop

Tags: jquery, treeview, dynatree

I am just starting to use Dynatree and stuck while updating the node display order to database while DragnDrop nodes to and fro.

I tried to google a bit and could not find any helpful links.

So, it will be greatly appreciated of any one can help or shared some helpful links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by storing keys on array and use that array to update database for display order index.

```
dynatree:
onDrop: function (node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
{
var resultsToClientNode = [];
sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);
$.map(sourceNode.getParent().getChildren(), function (nodelist) {
    if (nodelist.data.addClass == sourceNode.data.addClass) {
        resultsToClientNode.push(nodelist.data.key);
    }
});
// This array "resultsToClientNode" holds your node on DragDroped order.
// Call ajax to update in database.'
}
```